# How to prevent Axios from adding slash after baseURL

Tags: vue.js, axios, prefix, slash, base-url

In my Vue app I took the axios configuration to a seperate file *config.js*.

Content of *config.js*

```js
import axios from "axios";
const token = localStorage.getItem('user-token');
const baseUrl = `/api/v2.1/document.json&token=${token}&`;

export default () => {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: baseUrl
    })
}
```

In my Vuex store module *formFields.js* I have:

```js
import Api from '../../api/config';

// ...

const actions = {
    async getApiFields() {
        await Api().get('type=documentType').then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }).catch(e => {
            this.errors.push(e)
        });
    }
};
```

So, what is wrong? I don't know why axios adds ' **/** '

> Request URL: .../api/v2.1/document.json&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiI3ZTE2OTk5My00YTJiLTRhYWMtOGNiNi00ZTY0NGY2NjE3NTkiLCJhdWQiOiJNYWVzdHJvTElWRSIsInN1YiI6Ik1hZXN0cm9MSVZFIEFQSSIsImV4cCI6MTU4MDIwMTQ5OSwiaWF0IjoxNTgwMTk3NzE5fQ.PWstAQCDr6Atd_J26futucIBOBUZiFCcp0g5Y1JTYUs&/type=documentType

[Network tab screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhiTz.png)

How to prevent adding this slash?

Comment: Probably you should use the actual query string for your parameters?

Comment: Thanks @04FS, I wanted to stop reading token from localStorage in each file where I do axios request's (if possible).

Comment: I am talking about your baseUrl, where you appear to be trying to stuff what should probably be query string parameters, into the URL path instead.

Comment: First I think the endpoint `/document.json` shouldn't be part of the baseURL. Second, you need to find a way how to combine your default query ( `token` ) and your additional request query (`type`) . One solution would be to use axios interceptors. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** use axios interceptors

### Problem with combining default and additional query params

Use field `params` in the config object for `axios.create` , like

```js
import axios from "axios";
const token = localStorage.getItem('user-token');
const baseUrl = `/api/v2.1/`

/* Please note, an endpoint should not be part of the BaseURL */

export default () => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: baseUrl,
    params : { token : token }
  });
}

/* this will add ?token="XXX" query parameter to the url
```

```js
import Api from '../../api/config';

/* /document.json is your endpoint, and should not be part of the baseUrl */

const actions = {
  async getApiFields() {
    await Api().get('/document.json').then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    }).catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    });
  }
};
```

**The Problem with that is** you can't add additional query parameters, because they will override the default ones. So to have a solution for this, you could add a axios interceptor, which will add the token query parameter to each request.

### Solution: Use axios interceptor

```js
import axios from "axios";
const token = localStorage.getItem('user-token');
const baseUrl = `/api/v2.1/`

const instance = return axios.create({ baseURL: baseUrl });
instance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  config.params = {
   // add your default ones
   token: token,
   // spread the request's params
    ...config.params,
  };
  return config;
});
export default instance;
```

```js
import Api from '../../api/config';

const actions = {
  async getApiFields() {
    await Api().get('/document.json', {params:{type:'documentType'}})
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    }).catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    });
  }
};
```

Using an interceptor like this, will produce a request ( in this example ) like this:

`/api/v2.1/document.json?token=XXX&type=documentType`

You can read more about **Interceptors** here : https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

Comment: That's how the cookies crumble :) 
Thank you. Perfect solution!

Comment: Glad i could help

Comment: @czesi0 Please accept as answer if the answer is correct and helped you, thanks ! :)